# creating data frame using for loop for string data in R

Tags: r

I have csv file with following data.

i wanted to put this data in dataframe "dfSubClass".
After i will find unique subject list as "uniquesubject" and unique class list as "uniqueclass"form "dfSubClass".
Using "uniquesubject", "uniqueclass" and for loop i wanted to create all subject and class combinations as

[csv and expected data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cDhI.png)
I tried following but its not working.

```
dfSubClass <- read.csv("SubjectClass.csv",header = TRUE)
uniquesubject = unique(planningItems["Subject"])
uniqueclass = unique(planningItems["Class"])
newDF <- data.frame()
for(Subject in 1:nrow(uniquesubject)){
 for(Class in 1:nrow(uniqueclass)){
  newDF = rbind(newDF,c(uniquesubject[Subject,],uniqueclass[Class,]))
  }
}
```

this not giving me desired output please help .

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and [mcve]. For presenting your data use `dput()`, e.g. put the result of `dput(dfSubClass)` in your question, i.e. edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42999206/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the function `expand.grid` which will automatically generate all the combinations.

Also in your code `unique(planningItems["Subject"])`, it will return a data frame which is actually not a good idea for this case. A vector would be better.

Here is my code:

```
uniquesubject = unique(dfSubClass$Subject)
uniqueclass = unique(dfSubClass$Class)
newDF=expand.grid(uniquesubject,uniqueclass)
```

If using `for` loops, the main issue in your code is about the `rbind` function. Here is my code:

```
uniquesubject = unique(dfSubClass$Subject)
uniqueclass = unique(dfSubClass$Class)
newDF = data.frame()
for (Subject in 1:length(uniquesubject)){
    for (Class in 1:length(uniqueclass)){
         newDF=rbind(newDF,data.frame("Subject"=uniquesubject[Subject],"Class"=uniqueclass[Class]))
    }
}
```

I think the main different to your code is that I created a dataframe inside the `rbind()` instead of creating a vector using `c()`. This is to make sure the result is in dataframe structure instead of a matrix.

Comment: Hi Thanks Too Young, this giving me expected output but apart from this i wanted to perform some other operations in internal for loop. Same logic when i tried in c++ i am getting expected result but in R my newDF in with numerical value why its not showing string values ?

Comment: Also when you rbind vectors, in this case `c(uniquesubject[Subject,],uniqueclass[Class,])`, it will return a matrix instead of a dataframe. Therefore it will try to convert everything into numbers

Comment: This is not giving me correct result, its created newDF with all <NA>, and my code is too doing same. why its doing so ?

Comment: Sry, I made a mistake in the for loop, it should be `for(Subject in 1:length(uniquesubject))` instead of `for(Subject in uniquesubject)`. Same typo for `uniqueclass`. Now it should work

Comment: i have implemented same logic for my project and its working absolutely fine. Its giving me expected results too. Thanks